# Need to read 10,000 records from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am in a situation where currently I dont fetch more than 100s of records at a moment from core data but this will grow slowly over time , I want to keep the app ready for situations like 10000 records, should I implement this handling of records async or sync will still return the data having 10000 records much within a fraction of second ? I dont have experience in dealing with big size data on Core Data stack.

Comment: Where are you displaying this data? Tableview?

Comment: @jarora yes table view mostly

Comment: Please mention the reasons for downvoting.

Comment: @jarora may be they couldnt answer it :P , or probably they wanted to see a long trail of code but still dont answer it . Sometimes I feel Stackoverflow is filled with trolls.

Comment: The question is still very well related to programming if not then kindly suggest where should I ask this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use FRC(NSFetchedResultsController) along with FRC's NSFetchRequest's batchSize property which limits the number of core data objects in memory at an given time.

Please refer apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller).
Usage can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html).

**Edit:**
You may do the processing on your core data objects using a fetchRequest. Also, you may use indexing on a column to increase the performance of your query.

Comment: Basically I dont want to attach result set directly to TableView since we dont some processing before showing .

Comment: That's fine. You can do the processing in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You can fetch the coredata object at that indexPath from fetchedResultsController and then modify it to suit the view specifications.

Comment: No i mean requirement is gather the data first atleast 1000 records and then some processing and then display , so for this and some other reasons like I would like to keep loose coupling between the model and view , so really dont like to use it .

Comment: If you fetch 1000 objects in memory you are asking for trouble. My suggestion is to do that processing by making a fetchRequest with desired predicate. For example, counting how many of the first 1000 objects in the table have a value set as YES (this can be your predicate).

Comment: Well even if thats the case should this be a sync or async operation ?

Comment: Parsing 1000 objects should be really fast in DB. Plus if you can index that property, you will get the fetch request's result in a few milliseconds. So, sync should be just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150967/discussion-between-jarora-and-vishal-dharankar).

Comment: batchSize does not work with a NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: My bad. It was a typo. Corrected.